# Has $F(n)=\prod_{p\ {\rm prime}, p-1|n}p$ been studied?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Has $F(n)=\prod_{p\ {\rm prime}, p-1|n}p$ been studied?

This function interests me because for each prime $p$, the long-term average number of factors of $p$ in $n$ equals the long-term average number of factors of $p$ in $F(n)$.

Any non-trivial result would interest me, particularly the distribution of values of 
$\ln F(n)/\ln(n)$.

Comment: This is close the something related to Carmichael numbers and Korselt's criterion? Korselt showed that $n$ is a Carmichael number if and only if $n$ is squarefree and $p-1$ divides $n-1$ for all prime divisors $p$ of $n$. So not quite the same, but maybe the techniques used to prove infinitely many Carmichaels would be useful. This is in Alford, W. R.; Granville, Andrew; Pomerance, Carl; "There are infinitely many Carmichael numbers" *Ann. of Math.* (2) **139** (1994), no. 3, 703–722. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think $F(n)$ is (more-or-less) the denominator of the Bernoulli number $B_n$ by the Von Staudt–Clausen theorem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt–Clausen_theorem which refers you to http://oeis.org/A002445

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A160014